# supervisord and adding an environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, supervisord

Below is my kafka supervisor script tat I place in conf.d/kafka.conf.  I want to add an environment varable:

```
JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT:-9999}
```

I see from the supervisor docs:

```
[supervisord]
environment = KEY1="value1",KEY2="value2"
```

Does that mean I can add the below to  [program:kafka] or does it have to be in the section called [supervisord]

```
environment = JMX_PORT="${JMX_PORT:-9999}"


[program:kafka]
command = /var/lib/kafka-<%=@version%>-src/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /var/lib/kafka-<%=@version%>-src/config/server.properties 
process_name=%(program_name)s
autostart=true
autorestart=true

stopsignal=KILL
stopasgroup = true
killasgroup = true

stdout_logfile=/tmp/kafka.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=100MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10

stderr_logfile = /tmp/kafka.err
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10

[group:kafka_server]
programs=kafka
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs claim that it can be in either, but I have only ever seen it in [program] sections.

See: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html and http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment

That said, I would repeat it in the [program:*_*_] sections as that is where any sysadmin would expect to find it, not at the top of the file like in your example.